# How to interpret the DHARMa quantile residual plot?

Tags: residuals, glmm, assumptions, beta-distribution

We calculated a GLMM based on the beta distribution:

```
model_dur_red <- glmmTMB(tr_prop ~ treat + handler * day + corner * day  + (1|subject), data = data_red, family = beta_family(link = "logit"))
```

The dependent variable is a proportion of time spent receiving one of two treatments (treat) in a test of a fixed duration. All fixed effects are categorical with two levels, and we had 12 subjects. This is a reduced model; the full model also contained treat * day, but the interaction was not significant. We simulated the residuals:

```r
simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = model_dur_red)
```

and when I ran
`plot(simulationOutput)`,

I get these graphs:

[image: DHARMa quantile residual plots]

[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/548478/how-to-interpret-meaning-of-residual-vs-predicted-quantile-plots-in-dharma) it was suggested to add a quadratic effect to a model that produces a somewhat similar graph, but that does not work for our model, as it contains only categorical predictors. Is the deviation (most likely) a problem and is there anything we can do about it?
I also tried plotting the residuals against treat, the predictor of interest, but that didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the DHARMa developer. Regarding your question: there are two levels on which to answer this:

1. First of all, note that the evidence for a misfit is relatively weak. None if the tests to the left are significance, and also the quantile regression in the middle is n.s.. Just the upper quantile regression is significant, I would guess barely given the n.s. of the lower. While the quantile regressions are meant to help, they may optically exaggerate the strength of the signal with a low number of data points. Make the same plot with quantreg = F, and ask yourself if you see a strong pattern in there. I would suggest that it is relatively likely that wiggle you see in your residual pattern could also arise by chance, given the low number of data points.
2. Thus, given the low evidence, I wouldn't bend over backwards to get the pattern away, but you should consider if you missed something in your model specification. It could be interactions for the fixed effects but you can also consider (in glmmTMB) the dispformula to model dispersion - a dispersion dependency could create the same pattern.
3. When you do this, note that playing around too much and in particular making inclusion of fixed effects dependent on significance inflates type I error (p-hacking), so my advice would not to remove predictors just because they are n.s.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has been very helpful.